# why $ f(x,y) =-g(x,y)?$

Tags: calculus

I have  some confusion in Apostol  calculas book Page no $: 369$

Books Pdf link : https://www.academia.edu/4744309/Apostol_-_

My confusion is  marked  in red circle ,given below

[image]

why $ f(x,y)  =-g(x,y)?$

why negative  sign come ?

Comment: The ellipsoid has two parts: one with $z>0$ and one with $z<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y) \in S$. Let $E$ be the solid in question. Then:

$$(x,y,z) \in E \iff \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \le 1 \iff z^2 \le g(x,y)^2 \iff |z| \le g(x,y) \iff -g(x,y) \le z \le g(x,y).$$